# Definir limites dos municípios no GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou tentando criar mapas temáticos utilizando a **api** do google maps.
**Lendo a documentação** percebi que para colorir regiões eu preciso **definir todas as coordenadas Lat Long** do perímetro que eu quero.
Alguém que já teve algum problema semelhante:

- Sabe se existe algum site que disponibiliza as coordenadas dos municípios como esse aqui https://code.google.com/p/countrypoints/?
- Sabe se existe alguma opção na api onde os municípios podem ser informados pelo nome ou pelo código? Por exemplo: `new GPolygon(maps.saopaulo);`
- Sabe se existe alguma maneira mais fácil de se fazer?

Pesquisando na documentação, a única maneira que percebi como fazer isso é com o **Gpolygon**.
Um bom exemplo seria este aqui: http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/xtras/perfil.php?lang=&codmun=350950, onde a cidade de Campinas está em destaque.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse site do ibge que você passou nos serve bem, vamos fazer uma engenharia reversa nele para descobrir os polígonos!

Podemos começar endentendo como esse mapa é renderizado no site deles, para isso, podemos usar o developer tools do chrome e inspecionar o elemento que contém o mapa para entender da onde ele vem:

[image: O mapa vem de um iframe!]

O mapa vem de um iframe, interessante, vamos seguir esse link:

[image: Seguindo o iframe]

Esse é o resultado:

[image: Encontramos campinas!]

Vamos inspecionar o código fonte e tentar achar o código que adiciona esse shape no google maps:

[image: Codigo fonte do mapa]

A-há! Conseguimos a partir daí encontrar o webservice que ele acessa para pegar os dados do shape:

```
var codigo = jsget['codigo'];//33';//3303302';
var idnivel = jsget['idnivel'];//'MU';
var fcomp = jsget['fcomp'];//'100';//1000';

var urlServicoMapas = "shapes/" + codigo.substr(0, 2) + "/" + idnivel + "_M13_" + codigo + "_" + fcomp + ".json";
```

A partir daí deduzimos que a url nesse caso é:

http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/gmap/shapes/35/MU_M13_3550308_1000.json

Se você acessar essa url, vai ver que o shape vem truncado em algum formato, mas não tem problema, continuando a ler o código fonte, podemos ver que ele usa um "compactador", que está em outra url:

```
<script language="javascript" src="compactador.js"></script>
```

Esse é o código que nos interessa:

```
function descompacta(string) {
    var myArray = [];
    var str, str2, arr, arr2, lat, lng, f;
    var strings = string.split(" ");
    for (var i in strings)
    {
        str = strings[i];
        str2 = '';
        arr = [];
        arr2 = [];
        for (var j=0; j<str.length; j++)
        {
            switch (str.charAt(j))
            {
                case 'A': str2 += ',0'; break;
                case 'B': str2 += ',1'; break;
                case 'C': str2 += ',-1'; break;
                case 'D': str2 += ',2'; break;
                case 'E': str2 += ',-2'; break;
                case 'F': str2 += ',3'; break;
                case 'G': str2 += ',-3'; break;
                case 'H': str2 += ',4'; break;
                case 'I': str2 += ',-4'; break;
                case 'J': str2 += ',5'; break;
                case 'K': str2 += ',-5'; break;
                case 'L': str2 += ',6'; break;
                case 'M': str2 += ',-6'; break;
                case 'N': str2 += ',7'; break;
                case 'O': str2 += ',-7'; break;
                case 'P': str2 += ',8'; break;
                case 'Q': str2 += ',-8'; break;
                case 'R': str2 += ',9'; break;
                case 'S': str2 += ',-9'; break;
                default: str2 += str.charAt(j); break;
            }
        }
        arr = str2.split(",");
        f = arr.shift();
        lng = parseInt(arr[0])/f;
        lat = parseInt(arr[1])/f;
        arr2.push([lat, lng]);
        for (var j=2; j<arr.length; j+=2)

        {
            lng += parseInt(arr[j])/f;
            lat += parseInt(arr[j+1])/f;
            arr2.push([lat, lng]);
        }
        myArray.push(arr2);
    }
    return myArray;
}
```

Rodando o resultado do webservice nessa função, conseguimos um array com nosso shape:

http://pastebin.com/C7bVwNct

Comment: Aqui, por exemplo, tem o código dos municípios https://github.com/waltercruz/estados-municipios-ibge - Obviamente deve ter um lugar pra baixar os dados oficiais, mas o site do IBGE está cheio de links quebrados, não vou procurar agora :P.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @AndréAbadesso.