# Problema na utilização de função com arquivo truncado

Tags: javascript, funções

Em outro tópico eu fiz [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54916/definir-limites-dos-munic%C3%ADpios-no-googlemaps/55271#55271) e um amigo do site me ajudou.

Eu tentei utilizar a função com o arquivo truncado, entretanto o resultado foi:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que eu utilizei:

```
<script>
function dec(string)
    {// retorna a matris pura, descompactada
        var myArray = [];
        var str, str2, arr, arr2, lat, lng, f;
        var strings = string.split(" ");
        for (var i in strings)
        {
            str = strings[i];
            str2 = '';
            arr = [];
            arr2 = [];
            for (var j=0; j<str.length; j++)
            {
                switch (str.charAt(j))
                {
                    case 'A': str2 += ',0'; break;
                    case 'B': str2 += ',1'; break;
                    case 'C': str2 += ',-1'; break;
                    case 'D': str2 += ',2'; break;
                    case 'E': str2 += ',-2'; break;
                    case 'F': str2 += ',3'; break;
                    case 'G': str2 += ',-3'; break;
                    case 'H': str2 += ',4'; break;
                    case 'I': str2 += ',-4'; break;
                    case 'J': str2 += ',5'; break;
                    case 'K': str2 += ',-5'; break;
                    case 'L': str2 += ',6'; break;
                    case 'M': str2 += ',-6'; break;
                    case 'N': str2 += ',7'; break;
                    case 'O': str2 += ',-7'; break;
                    case 'P': str2 += ',8'; break;
                    case 'Q': str2 += ',-8'; break;
                    case 'R': str2 += ',9'; break;
                    case 'S': str2 += ',-9'; break;
                    default: str2 += str.charAt(j); break;
                }
            }
            arr = str2.split(",");
            f = arr.shift();
            lng = parseInt(arr[0])/f;
            lat = parseInt(arr[1])/f;
            arr2.push([lat, lng]);
            for (var j=2; j<arr.length; j+=2)

            {
                lng += parseInt(arr[j])/f;
                lat += parseInt(arr[j+1])/f;
                arr2.push([lat, lng]);
            }
            myArray.push(arr2);
        }
        document.write(myArray);
        return myArray;
    }
dec('{shapes:{3550308:"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"},bounds:{NORTE:-23.3563,SUL:-24.0084,LESTE:-46.3651,OESTE:-46.8262}}');

</script>
```

Alguém sabe em que eu errei na utilização da função?

Comment: Qual parte está dando `NaN,NaN...`?

Comment: Outra coisa, não use `for (var i in strings)`, pois `strings` é uma array. Use `for(var i=0; i<strings.length; i++)`.

Comment: O myArray sai NaN,NaN...,ele fica assim depois que passa pelo switch.Eu usei for(var i in strings) pois a função ja é pronta,e na resposta do André ele não fez nenhuma modificação

Comment: E qual é a entrada (`string`) que você está usando?

Comment: @bfavaretto Este link aqui:http://www.cidades.ibge.gov.br/gmap/shapes/35/MU_M13_3550308_1000.json

Answer (score 2):

O que você está fazendo errado é passar seu JSON inteiro para a função. Ela espera receber somente o conteúdo da chave `shapes`. Veja o código em funcionamento **[aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/qcLpLy4a/)**.

Não sei como você obtém esse JSON, dependendo do caso será necessário decodificá-lo como objeto antes de poder ter acesso a essa chave.